# yace doesn't show any data in grafana

Tags: amazon-s3, devops, monitoring, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

i have a dashboard in Grafana which was showing the data 6 months ago from yace cloudwatch exporter, right now it doesn't show any data although i could see the mertics from prometheus correctly via port-forwarding. do you have any clues ? (specially for s3 metrics).

Yace config as follows:

```
    - type: s3
      regions:
        - eu-central-1
      addCloudwatchTimestamp: false
      period: 172800
      length: 259200
      metrics:
        - name: NumberOfObjects
          statistics:
            - Maximum
          additionalDimensions:
            - name: StorageType
              value: AllStorageTypes
        - name: BucketSizeBytes
          statistics:
            - Sum
          additionalDimensions:
            - name: StorageType
              value: StandardStorage
        - name: BytesUploaded
          statistics:
            - Average
          period: 60
          length: 300
          additionalDimensions:
            - name: FilterId
              value: EntireBucket
```

and the deployment of yacl pod is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.26.3-alpha
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: prometheus
  name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        #iam.amazonaws.com/role: "arn:aws:iam::%%AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER%%:role/k8s/pod/id_CloudWatchMetricsExportAccess"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
        app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.26.3-alpha
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
          image: quay.io/invisionag/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter:v0.26.3-alpha
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - "--config.file=/cfg/yace-config.yaml"
          env:
            - name: gateway
              value: prometheus-pushgateway.monitor-system:9091
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /cfg
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.26.3-alpha
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: prometheus
  name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: metrics
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
      port: 9144
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter

---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.26.3-alpha
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: prometheus
  name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
spec:
  endpoints:
    - port: metrics
      interval: 60s
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alt-cloudwatch-exporter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the prometheus operator you will need to massage the data with an intermediate script pod else they will not be digestible. YACE creates metrics labels in the form of aws_yace, so unless you app is explicitly called yace you will not see anything